# Getting the lowest key and value from a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am doing some calculations between locations and I need to get the **lowest** key and value returned when it's done with the foreach. How do I achieve that?

```
// Los Angeles
$start_location = '34.048516, -118.260529';

$array=array(
'New York'=>'40.667646, -73.981803',
'Boston'=>'42.356909, -71.072573',
'Miami'=>'25.764618, -80.213501'
);


foreach($array as $x=>$x_value){

  echo $x." -> ".calculateDistance($start_location, $x_value);
  // Prints a number like "334".

}
```

For example, if `New York -> 132`, `Boston -> 204` and `Miami -> 393`, I need it to return the lowest one as:

`New York -> 132`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_search` and `min` function to get the min value and key of that element

```
$arr = [];
foreach($array as $x=>$x_value){
  $arr[$x]= calculateDistance($start_location, $x_value);
}
echo 'Key :- '.array_search(min($arr),$arr);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Value :-' .min($arr);
```

Output

```
Key :- New York
Value :- 132
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just keep a `$lowest_data` and `$lowest_dist` variable. Iterate through the array as you are doing. Calculate distance and update the `$lowest_dist` and `$lowest_data` variable accordingly.

```
<?php

$start_location = '34.048516, -118.260529';

$array=array(
    'New York'=>'40.667646, -73.981803',
    'Boston'=>'42.356909, -71.072573',
    'Miami'=>'25.764618, -80.213501'
);

$lowest_data = [];
$lowest_dist = -1;

foreach($array as $x=>$x_value){
  $distance = calculateDistance($start_location, $x_value)
  if($lowest_dist === -1 || $lowest_dist > $distance){
    $lowest_dist = $distance;
    $lowest_data = [
        $x => $x_value
    ];
  }
}


echo "Lowest distance ",$lowest_dist,PHP_EOL;
print_r($lowest_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a high value, then compare it in a loop, if the current value is lower, then replace it, if not continues.

```
$start_location = '34.048516, -118.260529';

$array = [
    'New York' => '40.667646, -73.981803',
    'Boston' => '42.356909, -71.072573',
    'Miami' => '25.764618, -80.213501',
];

$lowest_x = 1000.0;
$lowest_y = 1000.0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_replace('/([0-9\.]+),(.+)/s', '$1', $value) < $lowest_x) {
        $lowest_x = (float) trim(preg_replace('/([0-9\.]+),(.+)/s', '$1', $value));
    }

    if (preg_replace('/(.+),\s([0-9\.]+)/s', '$2', $value) < $lowest_y) {
        $lowest_y = (float) trim(preg_replace('/([0-9\.]+),(.+)/s', '$2', $value));
    }
}

var_dump($lowest_x);
var_dump($lowest_y);
```

I'm not sure, which value you wanted to be lower. You can do it using a regex.

Comment: I think they want the value with the least distance (as returned by `calculateDistance()`)